# The sms code from firebase does not match

Tags: firebase, android-studio, kotlin, authentication

I created a number sending activity and confirmation/otp fragment using firebase phone auth. When directed to the confirmation page, a 6-digit sms code from Firebase is sent to the phone number entered, but no matter what I do, the entered edittext and the codes from firebase do not match.
When I leave the edit text blank, it redirects to the fragment I want as if it were correct. Can you help me where am I making a mistake? My codes in the confirmation fragment are as follows;

class FragmentRegisterTelOnay : Fragment() {
var comingNumber = ""
lateinit var auth : FirebaseAuth
lateinit var callbacks : PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
var verificationID = ""
var comingCode : String = ""
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater,container: ViewGroup?,savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
var view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_register_activity_phone,container,false)
view.tvKullaniciTelNo.setText("+90"+comingNumber)
auth = Firebase.auth
setupCallBack()

```
  view.ileriButton.setOnClickListener {
      if (comingCode.equals(editTextOnayKodu.text.toString())){

        EventBus.getDefault().postSticky(EventBusDataEvents.KayitBilgileriniGonder("+90$comingNumber",null,verificationID,comingCode))
        val transaction = requireActivity().supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        transaction.replace(R.id.telefonOnayKod,FragmentRegisterDetailPhone())
        transaction.addToBackStack("TelOnayfragmentEklendi")
        transaction.commit()}
        else{
          Toast.makeText(activity,"Wrong Code",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
      }

  }

    val options = PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(auth)
        .setPhoneNumber("+90"+comingNumber)       // Phone number to verify
        .setTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // Timeout and unit
        .setActivity(requireActivity()) // Activity (for callback binding)
        .setCallbacks(callbacks)          // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
        .build()
    PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options)

    return view
}

private fun setupCallBack() {
    callbacks = object : PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

        override fun onVerificationCompleted(credential: PhoneAuthCredential) {
            if(!credential.smsCode.isNullOrEmpty()){
            comingCode = credential.smsCode!!
            progressBarOnayKod.visibility = View.GONE
            Log.e("Success","on verificationcompleted sms: " + comingCode)}
            else{
                Log.e("Error","onverification has not completed")
            }
        }

        override fun onVerificationFailed(e: FirebaseException) {
            Log.e("Error: ",e.localizedMessage)
            progressBarOnayKod.visibility = View.GONE
        }

        override fun onCodeSent(verificationId: String,token: PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken) {
            verificationID = verificationId
            progressBarOnayKod.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            Log.e("Codesent","oncodesent worked")
        }
    }
}

@Subscribe (sticky = true)
internal fun onTelefonEvent(kayitBilgileri: EventBusDataEvents.KayitBilgileriniGonder){
    comingNumber = kayitBilgileri.telNo.toString()
    Log.e("test",comingNumber)
}

override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this)
}

override fun onDetach() {
    super.onDetach()
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this)
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

first set the sha1 to firebase setting and generate google config.json then add to poject's root directory and add to build.gradle dependency.
it'll work properly

resources: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/283

Comment: Hi khaled. I've already done everything you said. Despite this, it doesn't. And sms code is coming. There is a mismatch problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to the official Firebase documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth?hl=en) the last step in authentication using sms code is to use the signInWithCredential() method, possibly with  with its help you will be able to solve your problem.  Here is part of the code to implement this method from the official Firebase documentation:

```
private fun signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential: PhoneAuthCredential) {
auth.signInWithCredential(credential)
    .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
        if (task.isSuccessful) {
            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
            Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success")

            val user = task.result?.user
        } else {
            // Sign in failed, display a message and update the UI
            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.exception)
            if (task.exception is FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                // The verification code entered was invalid
            }
            // Update UI
        }
    } }
```